# How to mutate in SWR with query parameters such page after success patch request?

Tags: javascript, next.js, swr

```
onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
        const { birthdate, ...userData } = values;
        let formattedBirthDate = formatDate(birthdate);
        const updateUserUrl = `/api/users/update/${id}`;

        try {
          // send a request to the API to update the source
          const res = await api.patch(
            updateUserUrl,
            {
              ...userData,
              birthdate: formattedBirthDate,
            },
            { headers: { "Auth-Token": authToken } }
          );

          if (res && res.data) {
            mutate('api/users?page=1&limit=10',{ ...user, userData, birthdate: formattedBirthDate });
            router.replace("/admin?page=1&limit=10");
            toast.success("Updated successfully");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.response) {
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            toast.error(error.response.data.message);
            console.log("Error response data: ", error.response.data);
            console.log("Error response status: ", error.response.status);
            console.log(
              "Error response headers: ,",
              error.response.headers
            );
          } else {
            console.log("Error entity error: ", error.message);
            toast.error(error.message);
          }
        }
```

I am trying to mutate the table data to have an updated data but it won't work if the mutate **URL** is not correct. If the current data fetch is from page 2, then the mutate **URL** will be `api/users?page=2&limit=10`. How can I know if the current data is from `page =2`?

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: Thank youu for the suggestion! I'll try stack snippets, just new here.